# デフォルト値の決定の仕方

Tags: mysql

下記認識で合っているでしょうか？

**DEFAULT指定がある時**
・その内容

**DEFAULT指定がない、かつNULLを許可している時**
・NULL

**DEFAULT指定がない、かつNULLを許可していない時**
・指定なし

**仮に上記認識が正しければ、**
・「DEFAULT値としてNULLを指定する場合」と、「DEFAULT値を指定しないが、NULLを許可する場合」は同じ？

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/data-type-defaults.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEFAULT in mysql is the same on most of the database native query.

DEFAULT指定がある時
・その内容

```
Create Table Test
(
     Id Int Auto_Increment Primary Key
    ,Name Varchar(30) Not Null
    ,TestValue Number Default 10
);

Insert Into Posts (Name) Values ('re9');

+---------+------+---------------------------------+
| Id      | Name | TestValue                       |
+---------+------+---------------------------------+
| 1       | re9  | 10                              |
+---------+------+---------------------------------+
```

DEFAULT指定がない、かつNULLを許可している時
・NULL

```
TestValue Varchar(30)          --- NULL ok
```

DEFAULT指定がない、かつNULLを許可していない時
・指定なし

```
TestValue Varchar(30) NOT NULL --- NULL not ok
```

The last question depends on if the null value is allowed in your column. For any non constraint violations or non NOT NULL definitions defined in the sql columns you will know if it is allowed.

Below are all the same:

```
TestValue type                   --- null ok
TestValue type NULL              --- null ok
TestValue type DEFAULT NULL      --- null ok
TestValue type NULL DEFAULT NULL --- null ok
```